# ValueError: indices and data should have the same size

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, nlp

I have this error when Iam applying 'Dbscan' on amazon review data set.can any one help me

```
 from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
    cv=CountVectorizer()
    X=cv.fit_transform((X_train))
    from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
  
    
    clustering = DBSCAN(eps=1.0,n_jobs=-1).fit(X)



C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\compressed.py in check_format(self, full_check)
    173         # check index and data arrays
    174         if (len(self.indices) != len(self.data)):
--> 175             raise ValueError("indices and data should have the same size")
    176         if (self.indptr[-1] > len(self.indices)):
    177             raise ValueError("Last value of index pointer should be less than "

ValueError: indices and data should have the same size
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please post the full stack trace? Also, I recommend that you read [How to ask questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and format your question for readability while providing full [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't provide any data sample, i just implemented it with an expected input and it works. Probably you have problem with your input shape or type.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv=CountVectorizer()
X_train = [
           'ali is a good man',
           'ali is here',
           'a different sentence'
]
X=cv.fit_transform(X_train)
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
  
    
clustering = DBSCAN(eps=1.0,n_jobs=-1).fit(X)
```